# Is there any way to catch js/css load error in browser in application we are developing by javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, error-handling

The requirement is sending some measurement/log back to backend regarding js/css errors in browser.
I looked in many place but seems like there is no way to do this.

Comment: Why would you expect resources to fail loading in your application?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I didn't say I expect that to happen but there is a chance. if there are some times that user cannot download then I would like to know.

Comment: Maybe I should think about alternative way like doing something on server side/cdn instead. thank

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> If the script is blocked, an error is sent to the element, if not a load event is sent.

so actually I can add `onerror` attribute to those each script tags and invoke the error handler.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).